# URL of document template of content type

Tags: 2013, content-type

I need URL of document template of custom content type.

[image]

I am not talking about getting shortcut link that users can easily click instead of clicking to Files > New Document > Template. I want only URL of document template inside of content type, regardless of whether the content type is linked to a library or not.

I thought of getting it from ShP Designer somehow, but I didn't find it.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see all the document templates through SharePoint Designer. The location for the specific document template is: `[siteurl]/_cts/[content type name]/[document name]`

In SP Designer you can find all content types in `All Files->_cts` folder.

Comment: Thank you on reply. I tried that before posting question and all I can get is to download template to my workstation. I can't open it in web browser/web app feature.

Comment: Well, that's the best you can do here... There is no integration with word online in this case so you could edit the template directly... You can only download it, edit it and upload it back.